# Undefined method getDoctrine

Tags: php, symfony, controller, doctrine, undefined

I am a beginner on Symfony 6 and I am blocked because I have an error message: "Undefined method getDoctrine" with Intelephense

Here is my code:

```
 #[Route('/recettes', name: 'app_recettes')]

    public function index(int $id): Response
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $recette = $em->getRepository(Recettes::class)->findBy(['id' => $id]);

        return $this->render('recettes/index.html.twig', [
            'RecettesController' => 'RecettesController',
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Does this class or its super classes have a method called getDoctrine()? You may been to provide us some more information about this class for us to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your controller should extends `AbstractController` from `use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;`

You should not use `getDoctrine()->getManager()` in symfony 6. If you look into the method from `AbstractController` you can see:

```
trigger_deprecation('symfony/framework-bundle', '5.4', 'Method "%s()" is deprecated, inject an instance of ManagerRegistry in your controller instead.', __METHOD__);
```

You should just autowire your entity manager in your method or constructor and use it directly.

```
private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

#[Route('/recettes', name: 'app_recettes')]
public function index(int $id): Response
{
    $recette = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Recettes::class)->findBy(['id' => $id]);

    return $this->render('recettes/index.html.twig', [
        'RecettesController' => 'RecettesController',
    ]);
}
```

You could also autowire your RecettesRepository directly instead of the entity manager if you just want to fetch some data.

I'm guessing that you want to show a specific resource by using its id. You probably want to add something `/{id}` in your route:

```
#[Route('/recettes/{id}', name: 'app_recettes')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dylan response is really good !

If you want to fecth a specific recette (blog de cuisine?), you can autowire the 'recette' as an argument :

```
#[Route('/recettes/{id}', name: 'app_recettes')]
public function index(Recette $recette): Response
{
    return $this->render('recettes/index.html.twig', [
         'recette' => $recette,
     ]);

}
```

To do so, don't forget to install and import :

`use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Entity;`

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 6, `getDoctrine()` method have been removed. Instead of it you can use `$doctrine` variable. To use it follow this steps.

use this in your controller

```
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry as PersistenceManagerRegistry;
```

pass this argument into the your index function

```
public function index(int $id,  PersistenceManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
```

Access `$doctrine` variable like this.

```
$em = $doctrine->getManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Symfony 5.4, the getDoctrine() method in the abstract controller is deprecated, and it's removed in Symfony 6.

You've already injected the manager registry into your controller action, so replace the $this->getDoctrine() call with the $doctrine variable.

Like this:

```
// src/Controller/IndexController.php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    private $doctrine;

    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        // Access Doctrine using $this->doctrine
        $entityManager = $this->doctrine->getManager();

        // Your controller logic here
        return $this->render('index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Comment: Just injectt he Repository you need for the controller that's working on the entity.  If you are working with multiple entities,  Just inject `EntityManagerInterface` and you can `$entityManager->getRepository(...)->...`